# POSTGIS query - extracting common point from polygon data

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a polygon dataset and need to find the single common point where 3 polygons meet. I'm approaching this by creating duplicate tables and comparing them to the main one (polygon_table a). I've managed to obtain the relevant polygons with the following query, but can't get it as a point.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.geom
FROM polygon_table a, polygon_table t1, polygon_table t2, polygon_table t3
WHERE a.id <> t1.id 
AND a.id <> t2.id
AND a.id <> t3.id
AND t1.id <> t2.id
AND t1.id <> t3.id
AND t2.id <> t3.id
AND ST_TOUCHES(a.geom, t1.geom)  = 't'
AND ST_TOUCHES(a.geom, t2.geom)  = 't'
AND ST_TOUCHES(a.geom, t3.geom)  = 't'
```

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Your query finds the whole polygon that intersects with other polygons. I guess you'd rather want to have just a part of it (a point in your case). You might try with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_Intersection(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) wkb_geometry
FROM polygon_table a, polygon_table b 
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry)
AND a.id <> b.id
```